# The class does not have a default constructor

Tags: dart

Webstorm errors `The class Task does not have a default constructor` on `GreatTask`, I expect `Task` being a default constructor of `Task.

I am looking forward to create a `contract` of a `Task`, such that upon `Task.run()`, for each member of the list `chain` `Task.chain[i]` gets executed as it was a member of `Task`, otherwise I expect an `uncaught error`.

I am wondering what should I correct as first, the code or the configuration of Webstorm.

```
abstract class Task {
  List chain;

  Task(this.chain);

  void run() {
    this.chain.forEach((el) => this.el());
  }
}


class GreatTask extends Task {
  List chain;

 GreatTask(this.chain);

  String hi() {
    return 'hi';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "default constructor" is (technically) the one that is added if you don't add any constructors yourself. It'll be `YourClass(): super();`.

The term "default constructor" is also commonly used about any no-name zero-argument generative constructor. That's what the error here is saying.
Because `GreatTask(this.chain);` is the same as `GreatTask(this.chain): super();` and the superclass `Task` does not have a no-name zero-argument generative constructor for `super()` to refer to, you have an error.

Günther's answer solves the problem by making the `GreatTask` constructor call the existing `Task(List list)` constructor instead of the non-existing `Task()` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

@Kikerova was right, I don't know why he deleted his good answer. 
If you add your own constructor, no default constructor is created anymore and you need to explicitly call the or a super constructor.

I assume you don't want to add (override) the `List chain;` field in your subclass because the superclass already contains it. If you want to initialize a field of the super class you can't use the short form with `this.chain` in the constructor argument list.

I assume this is what you want instead:

```
class GreatTask extends Task {

 GreatTask(List chain) : super(chain);

  String hi() {
    return 'hi';
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to call the default constructor even if i have defined a constructor?

Comment: If you add any constructor, there won't be a default constructor. You can implement it explicitely `GreatTask(); /* default */ 
 GreatTask.someName(List chain) : super(chain);`

Comment: but it says `this class already has a default contructor` when I implement it explicitly.

Comment: As soon as you add any constructor explicitly, no default constructor will be added automatically and you can only have 1 unnamed constructor. You need to make the 2nd, 3rd, ..., named constructors (`someName`) in my previous comment.